# Increase rotational velocity of synchronous motor

Tags: motor, frequency, synchronous, vintage, synchronous-motor

I recently got my hands on a Philips PM8110 (a single pen recorder which is basically an analog printer for voltages) which sadly provides paper with a velocity of 8 cm/hour. Although this would be ideal for measuring temperatures of the environment, it's not really efficient for what I want to use it for (toying around with it since this is an old inefficient technology but I just love the device). Now, I figured out that the paper supply is driven by a synchronous motor which, when supplied with a 50 Hz 100 V signal (supplied from wall via transformer) rotates once per hour.

Since I want to increase the paper speed to around 8 cm/min, I would need to supply the synchronous motor with a 3000 Hz signal [a high accuracy is not really required].

**Question 1**: Not looking at how to obtain this signal yet, is this even a possible method? Can the synchronous motor even handle such a huge increase in frequency?

**Question 2**: Suppose the answer to question 1 is yes, how can I multiply the incoming frequency by 60 (or about, so it might become x64 if multipliers would be used). Is there an IC for this? In the ideal situation, I would like to keep this motor (since it's the original) and with a switch, switch between the original 8 cm/hour to a side with a potentiometer for a variable paper speed. I looked on the internet of course but could not find a definitive answer on whether or not there is actually a really simple, small, realizable method.

I guess that if the answer to question 1 is 'no', I would have to search for another motor with the desired rotational velocity (whether this would still be a synchronous motor or not) and install it in the device which, as mentioned previously, is not preferred. Any other methods or some inspiration is also really appreciated.

I would love to get some insight into this,

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect to increase the speed of rotation of your synchronous motor by 60x.
In addition your paper drive is most probably a motor and gearbox combination; so NOT just a synchronous motor.

You have not specified the number of poles in your motor, so it's hard to guess at what the actual shaft speed is. You can look [here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/synchronous-motor-frequency-speed-d_649.html) for more information.

[image]

Notice that in the above table you are talking about raising the speed of a 12 pole motor from 500 rpm to 30000 rpm. You can guess whether that would be successful.

Your best bet is to replace the motor/gearbox with a new one. While you could look for a synchronous motor for this task, your best possibility would be to replace the motor/gearbox with a stepper motor with no gearbox (much less engineering to do). With a stepper motor you can get controllers that will drive the shaft at up to 256x microsteps and the feed rate is then defined by a simple to generate pulse frequency.

Comment: And once you get the paper going faster, you may well find that the bandwidth of the pen drive isn't up to maintaining accuracy.  I suspect it will, because they probably had other models that did go around as fast as you want (probably with the same motor but a different gearbox).

Comment: I would see if I could replace the motor/gearbox with my own stepper motor & gearbox (with less reduction), and a suitable controller.